# OBS libobs-sharp - Cannot get to run

Tags: c#, obs

I would like to interact with OBS via a c# wrapper.

I have come across the following, which looks like it could help, but I am struggling to get anything to work.

https://github.com/ilosvideos/libobs-sharp#libobs-sharp

It has the following installation instructions, however I am unsure exactly what these mean?  I'd like to be able to include the libobs-sharp dll in my project and access the functions it gives, I have tried adding the dll to the C:\Program Files (x86)\obs-studio\bin\64bit folder but this hasn't worked.

Has anyone any suggestions?

> Installation
>   Recommended: Place libobs-sharp to root of the obs-studio directory (obs-studio/libobs-sharp)
>
> Debugging: Use the obs-studio output folder as project working directory (obs-studio\build\rundir\Debug\bin\32bit)
>
> Binaries: In the same directory as other obs-studio output files.

Comment: Never put a dll into the project bin folder.  It can easily be deleted when you do a rebuild all. Instead put the dll into the project folder and then add to project use Add Existing item.  Then the compiler will automatically put dll into the bin folder. And if you change the project build options it will put dll into the correct bin subfolder.

Comment: Is the project set to CPU Any?